# How to remove a gap between widget and window corner in GTK?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm new to GTK+. I wanted the GtkEntryBar to be placed at the left edge of the window. I wrote `gtk_widget_set_halign(search_bar, GTK_ALIGN_START);`, but for some reason there was a gap between search bar and edge of the window. I tried different options: I set expand to FALSE and wrote margin and padding 0px in css. But this gap does not disappear. What do I wrong and how to solve this problem?

here is my code:

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
  GtkWidget * mainwin;          //GTK_WINDOW
  GtkWidget * search_bar;         //GTK_SEARCH_BAR
  GtkWidget * search_entry;         //GTK_SEARCH_ENTRY

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  mainwin = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  search_bar = gtk_search_bar_new();
  search_entry = gtk_search_entry_new();

  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(mainwin), 1080, 650);
  gtk_search_bar_set_search_mode(GTK_SEARCH_BAR(search_bar), TRUE);
  gtk_widget_set_halign(search_bar, GTK_ALIGN_START);

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(mainwin), search_bar);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(search_bar), search_entry);

  gtk_widget_show_all(mainwin);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

and this is css code:

```
searchbar, box {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

P. S. I added a photo. This is what it looks like now. And I want to remove these gaps.

[image: Here is a screenshot how it looks like]

Comment: Did you tried g_object_set( entry, “margin”, 0, NULL ); ?

Comment: @Michi, Thanks for your advice. I tried your suggestion but it didn't solve the problem.